# When I set the availability of my app for a future date does it still retain a "new" status

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I know this isn't a programming question, but since a lot of people here are iPhone developers i'll ask anyways.

My iPhone app got approved at around 11:30PM last night, and today I decided to download it to check it out. I noticed that there was a little problem with the app so I decided to change the availability date to a later date, in order to remove it from the app store (I'd rather not have the first version of my app have a problem...it would look kinda bad). So I submitted an update with the fix.

Now i'm wondering, my app wasn't on the App Store for even a day so when the update is approved and I make it available again will it be considered "new" and at least be seen in the App Store for a few days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. Also, you'll be able to change the availability date if you like.

Comment: the reason i'm asking is because my app got approved the about 12hours later when i downloaded it I noticed a bug so I decided to remove it from the app store and in the meanwhile i've sent an update with the fix. So even in this situation will it still be considered new when I make it available again?

Comment: In that case no, it won't be in the new apps list as the go-live data will be from the first version. They use to go back into the new list but lots of people abused that by submitting new versions every week just to be on the list. But, since you don't have a user base already, I suggest you delete the initial app (careful to change it's name to something else as once deleted a name can't be reused) and submit a brand new app. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: that is exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you very much!!